# Can I define implicit cast behaviour for a class in Haxe?

Tags: class, casting, haxe, implicit

Is it possible to define implicit casts for classes?
For instance, I have a class `Color`:

```
class Color {
    public var r: Int;
    public var g: Int;
    public var b: Int;

    public function new(?r: Int = 0, ?g: Int = 0, ?b: Int = 0) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

If I have a `Array<Int>` like this:

```
var myIntegerArray = [255, 0, 255]; // color written in RGB as an array
var c: Color = myIntegerArray; // <= how to make this possible?
trace(c.r);
```

I tried `@:from` on a static function in my class:

```
@:from
static public function fromArray(a: Array<Int>) {
    return new Color(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
}
```

but the compiler is still not happy about this (`Error: Array<Int> should be Color`).

I know I could just use the static function like `var c = Color.fromArray(myIntegerArray);` but I'm curious whether or not it is possible to implicitly cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, implicit cast for normal class is impossible. But you have three solutions:

1. Create `abstract Color(Array<Int>)` instead `class`;
2. Use "chain" e.g. `class Color` > `abstract ColorAbs` > `Array<Int>`;
3. Use `haxe.extern.EitherType<Color, Array<Int>>`;

I don't recommend the second solution.

Comment: thanks! i wrote the `abstract Color` with a `typedef ColorType {r,g,b}` and `@:from` keyword but i can't access the fields after the cast (ex. when I write `trace(color.r)` I get `Color has no field r`

Comment: `EitherType` only works for extern code. By the way you might want to have a look at thx.color that uses abstract for colors. https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.color